# Type mismatch in range

Tags: excel, vba, range, type-mismatch

I am trying to copy a filtered range from a master dataset to a spreadsheet for each country (loop). I am getting a type mismatch error for `Set rng1 = ws2.Range("E2:L" And lRow1)`  when I set a range in the filtered sheet. Can someone please help me identify the cause of the mismatch?

```
Sub CopyData_To_TemplateWorkbook2()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SavePath, TemplatePath, TemplateFile As String
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, wbws1, wbws2, wbws3 As Worksheet
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim MSi As Variant
Dim lRow1, lRow2 As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

TemplatePath = "C:\Users\xyz\Test\"
TemplateFile = "Template_blank.xlsx"

SavePath = "C:\Users\xyz\Test\"

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Responses 2006 2020")

ws1.Select

For i = 2 To 5 'Loop through list of country names

    Set MSi = ws1.Range("A" & i)

    ws2.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    ws2.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=MSi     'Filter Criteria1 = i
    
    lRow1 = ws2.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws2.Range("E2:L" And lRow1) 'Type mismatch here

    'Set rng1 = ws2.Range("E2:L") 'Application-defined or object-defined error here if used
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TemplatePath & "Template_blank.xlsx", Editable:=True)

    Set wbws1 = wb.Sheets("Cover sheet")
    Set wbws2 = wb.Sheets("Responses")

    wbws1.Range("B2").Value = MSi
    wbws2.Range("B2").Value = MSi
      
    lRow2 = wbws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'But there is no last row - blank sheet
    
    Set rng2 = wbws2.Range("A6:H") ' And lRow2 ??

    rng2.Value = rng1.Value
    
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath _
    & MSi & "_text" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set rng1 = Nothing


ws1.Select

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: A line above you concatenate strings with `&` (as it should be), why `And` in this line?

Comment: `And` is an boolean operator. You can use it for boolean variables or use it for numbers to perform an arithmetic AND, but it throws a type mismatch for strings.